# Is it possible to have a blank row after each record in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

I have code that gives me details about each account, whether if they have made a payment, if there is still payment due or if they Paid in Full.

The part of the code in question is as follows:

```
SELECT AccountNumber AS [Account Number]
      ,CxFullName AS [Customers Full Name]
      ,Amount  
      ,Comment AS [Reason Comment]
ORDER BY [Account Number]
```

I've made the report in SSRS where the results I get are as follows:

```
Account Number  Customer's Full Name    Amount  Reason Comment
10071234        Tina Turner             326.38  PAYMENT
10071234        Tina Turner             852.24  AMOUNT DUE
10182345        Whitney Houston          57.20  PAYMENT
10182345        Whitney Houston                 PAID IN FULL
```

As you can see there is no space between Tina Turner's and Whitney Houston's records (no pun intended)

Is there a way to add a blank row space between each Customer's records? A Group by, perhaps? I've tried grouping by account number but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid. I was trying to find a complicated solution for a simple problem.

1. Under Row Groups, I clicked on Add Group > Parent Group > Selected 'Account Number'.
2. Clicked on 'Add Total' > 'After' and created a row for Totals. I didn't need to show Totals, so I just deleted all the contents of that row.
3. Then I added a light grey FILL to that row.

Now my report looks much neater and easier to read.

Some problems have an simple solution. Who knew?